# mplcursors show data when hover and/or when clicked on datapoint

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

is it possible for mplcursors to show data when hover over data point and also when clicked on it on the same plot?i have tried to set both but did not work.

below example have 2 plots; first plot have mplcursors to display annotation when when clicked on data point. second plot have mplcursors to display annotation when when hover on data point. dwesired outcome is to have both mplcursors behaviors (display annotation when when hover and when clikced) on same plot.
Also is it possible for one **scatter1** to have different mplcursors behavior than **scatter2**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
x2 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

#first plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Multiple draggable annotations")
scatter1 = ax.scatter(x1,x1)
scatter2 = ax.scatter(x2,x2)
mplcursors.cursor(multiple=True).connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.draggable(True))
plt.show()


#second plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Hover on point annotations")
scatter1 = ax.scatter(x1,x1)
scatter2 = ax.scatter(x2,x2)
mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you create a fully reproducible minimal example? Such an example would clarify what exactly you understand by "marker", as matplotlib has different elements with markers.  Also, a matplotlib "line" could have more than 2 vertices; it is not clear if that is needed in your case. As a guess to an answer, you'll probably need two cursors. (Here is [an example with two cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59800059/how-to-use-two-mplcursors-simultaneously-for-a-scatter-plot-of-two-sets))

Comment: @JohanC, added example above.

Comment: adding hover and multipe to same mplcursors does not work. the way hover works is to remove annotation when hover is not there. this does not do that. can you elaborate on the another approach? can you try to answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple mplcursors active at the same time. To reduce confusion, you can change the background color for one of them.

The [`hover=`](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mplcursors.html#mplcursors.HoverMode) parameter supports three modes:

- `False` / `NoHover`: nothing happens when hovering
- `True` / `Persistent`: the annotation pops up when hovering and stays visible until hovering over another element
- `Transient`: the annotation pops up when hovering, but disappears when hovering away

The default persistent mode can be confusing when mixed with the permanent annotations.

Example code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
x2 = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title("Hover to see coordinates. Left click to\npersist and drag. Right click to remove.")
scatter1 = ax.scatter(x1, x1)
scatter2 = ax.scatter(x2, x2)

cursor1 = mplcursors.cursor(multiple=True)
cursor1.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.draggable(True))

cursor2 = mplcursors.cursor(hover=mplcursors.HoverMode.Transient)
cursor2.connect("add", lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_backgroundcolor('pink'))

plt.show()
```

[image: two mplcursors hover and drag]

Comment: is it possible to pickle mplcursors annotations?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you should just try?  They are part of the plot.  I suppose you can save the annotations as shown, but you'll need to implement the hover functionality again. If needed, you can create a new question, referring to this one.